# systemd: Start service/script IMMEDIATELY after mount

Tags: linux, debian, mount, services, systemd

On a system running Debian 8 with Systemd, I am trying to run a service **immediately** after /var is mounted.  The custom service copies some essential files to /var, and it must be run before any other services that depend on /var.  How can I configure systemd to run my custom service after /var is mounted but before other services?

**EDIT**: As a side note, `/` is mounted read-only, and I am trying to mount `/var` as a tmpfs.  Then, I copy some files to `/var` during boot-up.  Prior to systemd, this was a simple change to `/etc/init.d/mountkernfs.sh`... now it seems to be a systemd nightmare. :(

Comment: Well, you can always generalize the above, it is not that difficult.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae - ???